# How to compile BCC on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux-kernel, clang, bpf, bcc-bpf

I am trying to compile the BCC BPF framework (https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed all the instructions for 18.04, but of course; they fail.

The issue i have seems to be clang-related though

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h:15,
                 from /home/matt/code/bpf/bcc/src/cc/frontends/clang/loader.cc:43:
/usr/local/include/clang/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.h:157:15: note: candidate: ‘static bool clang::CompilerInvocation::CreateFromArgs(clang::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<const char*>, clang::DiagnosticsEngine&)’
  157 |   static bool CreateFromArgs(CompilerInvocation &Res,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/clang/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.h:157:15: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
make[2]: *** [src/cc/frontends/clang/CMakeFiles/clang_frontend.dir/build.make:63: src/cc/frontends/clang/CMakeFiles/clang_frontend.dir/loader.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:982: src/cc/frontends/clang/CMakeFiles/clang_frontend.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

How do i get BCC compiling on Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: What version of Clang do you have?

Comment: i've tried every version from 6 to 10. howeverr when i use look at how it's compiling, it's using `/usr/bin/c++` to compile, which is `g++`, not clang...

Comment: You compile bcc with gcc, but then bcc compiles program to BPF using Clang. For that it uses libclang and libllvm. To know which version of LLVM/Clang it's using, you can check the output of the `cmake` command during the installation.

Comment: oh thanks! :) Do you know what versions of clang/llvm bcc supports?

Comment: It should be all starting with 3.7, but it's possible there could be issues with the latest releases or maybe with the oldest if that wasn't properly tested. If you tell me with what  version you have this issue, I can try to reproduce and maybe fix it.

Comment: Thanks, i'm not entirely sure the lines i should be looking for but i see `as -I /usr/lib/llvm-8/include/../tools/clang/include -I /home/mark/code/bpf/bcc/src -I /home/mark/code/bpf/bcc/build/src -I /home/mark/code/bpf/bcc/build/src/cc -I /home/mark/code/bpf/bcc/src/cc -I /home/mark/code/bpf/bcc/build/src/cc/frontends/b -I /home/mark/code/bpf/bcc/src/cc/frontends/b -I
`
So i asssume it's llvm-8 ?

Comment: Ah maybe this is what you want:

```
$ cmake ..
-- Latest recognized Git tag is v0.14.0
-- Git HEAD is ceb458d6a07a42d8d6d3c16a3b8e387b5131d610
-- Revision is 0.14.0-ceb458d6
-- Found LLVM: /usr/lib/llvm-8/include 8.0.1
-- Using static-libstdc++
-- Could NOT find LuaJIT (missing: LUAJIT_LIBRARIES LUAJIT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning at tests/python/CMakeLists.txt:6 (message):
  Recommended test program 'arping' not found

```

Comment: @FUJI Goro's answer worked for me..i needed to use the `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-7` to get it to work. I think you guys should add this to your README as it caused me a lot of tears, hehe

Comment: I don't contribute much to that project anymore, so it's probably best if you report it upstream directly (the version breakage, not the documentation change since it should work for all versions >3.7 AFAIK).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of BCC v0.14.0-a28337a, I have to use llvm-7 instead of the latest LLVM. Also, `-DPYTHON_CMD=python3` or installing Python2 (or `python` command) is required because Python2 is no longer installed by default. Other dependencies listed in https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md#ubuntu---source are also required.

I can build it on my Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

```
cmake -Bbuild -DPYTHON_CMD=python3 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/llvm-7
make -Cbuild -j$(nproc)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was use a different branch, actually the latest tag, you can check that at github site for the project: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc.git

One I did a `git checkout v0.24.0 # for example` it worked.

**Hint:**
Probably the main branch may not be the best choice as it may be broken due to the latest commit, changing for the last stable release has already worked for me on many other different projects.